# Where to find UI examples

Tags: user-interface

Programmers usually don't pay much attention to user interfaces and focus more on functionalities but users first judge the product by its appearance so it is necessary to make nice user interface for web, desktop and mobile apps.

Personally I don't like to spend much time for user interface design and sometimes try to look for some examples and then modify the existing design.

Does anyone know any good web resource with collection of user interfaces for web, desktop and mobile devices?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally I find [quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/) a nice site for that purpose

Comment: +1 for quince.  Not only does it show you a concept, it explains when, where and WHY to pick one approach over another.

Answer (score 5):

I use Balsamiq Mockups and their site has a good collection of [mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/examples) you can look at. Also [UI-patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/) and [inspireUx](http://www.inspireux.com/) are both really good resources.

Answer (score 2):

This one may be useful: http://www.flickr.com/groups/ilovewireframes

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at the Yahoo design pattern and particularly the wireframe stencil kit that you can use to design your user interface: http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/wireframes/

Answer (score 2):

Design pattern libraries are very useful, but it can be a bit dangerous to look at them and "pick your favourites". This is not how good UI design happens. Different design patterns are useful for different contexts.

You may be better off by starting with a review of competitor products, and building up your own understanding of what works and what doesn't within your applications specific context.

Answer (score 1):

This [Design Patterns set](http://www.flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe/collections/72157600001823120/) by [Chris Messina](http://factoryjoe.com/blog/about/) on Flickr.com seems to be good.

Answer (score 1):

For the web I recommend you to take a look at those links:
http://layouts.ironmyers.com/
http://www.webreference.com/authoring/style/sheets/layout/advanced/
http://www.code-sucks.com/css%20layouts/
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/

Answer (score 1):

Not a web resource, but the user interface for [BBEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBEdit) from 
Bare Bones Software (text editor, Mac OS) is the best I have 
ever encountered and is worth studying and emitating. What is learned from 
such a study can be applied on any platform, not just Mac OS.

"Best" = simple to use for beginners, **intuitive** gradual discovery 
of more advanced features.